# Javascript click to change background color and counting click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I have code as below:

```
const btnHappyOne = document.getElementById("happy-btn-1");
const btnHappyTwo = document.getElementById("happy-btn-2");
const btnHappyThree = document.getElementById("happy-btn-3");

function changeHappyBgColor(e){
    let happyColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    if (happyColor != "red") {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";     
    }
    else {

        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
        
    }
}

btnHappyOne.addEventListener('click', changeHappyBgColor);
btnHappyTwo.addEventListener('click', changeHappyBgColor);
btnHappyThree.addEventListener('click', changeHappyBgColor);
```

This code change color of button when I click. My problem is that I want add some codes to count number of button whenever it change to red. When I click to change background color to none, the number of button also degrease. Thank you.

Comment: Put an increment variable `let reds = 0;` above `function changeHappyBgColor`. Then after `e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red"; reds++;`.

Comment: toggle a class.... reinventing checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var number=0;` below consts, in if block use `number++`; and in else block use `number--`;
You can track it in console to see the value, `console.log(number);`
I hope this is what are you asking for